# How to get access field in Delphi using RTTI?

Tags: delphi, field, delphi-2010, rtti

Consider the following:

```
TFieldType = class
  fValue: string;
end;

TMainClass = class
private
  Ffield: TFieldType;
public
  function GetValue: string;
end;
```

In TMainClass.GetValue I'm tryin get values of TMainClass fields:

```
function TMainClass.GetValue;
begin
  vCtx := TRTTIContext.Create;
  vType := vCtx.GetType(Self.ClassInfo);
  for vField in vType.GetFields do
    vField.GetValue(
        //Here's the trouble, because i don't know how to get the instance
    );
```

May be there are another ways of getting values of fields which are the instances of another classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to pass the instance as the a parameter of GetValue like

`vField.GetValue(self);`

For a better understanding of Rtti read the [remarkable articles about RTTI](http://robstechcorner.blogspot.com/2009/09/so-what-is-rtti-rtti-is-acronym-for-run.html) by Robert Love. For this problem specialy this one about [Properties and Fields](http://robstechcorner.blogspot.com/2009/09/so-what-is-rtti-rtti-is-acronym-for-run.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i've read these articles, but it seems not so attentively. Your answer resolvd my problem.

Comment: Second link is same one... wrong link pasted ? I think he ment to paste this one: http://robstechcorner.blogspot.com/2009/09/exploring-trttimember-descendants-in.html